# Extracting multiple values from list and storing them in data frame using R?

Tags: r, list, data-frame

I have a list of 3 SpatialPolygonsDataFrames. Every element has a number which is the perimeter. I want through a loop to store the numbers into one cell of a data frame like: 154,526,442. I tried to do that like this (in R):

```
for (i in 1:3){
  if (i ==1){
   datafr$perimeter[1]=mylist[[i]]@data$perim
  }else{
    datafr$perimeter[1]=mylist[[1]]@data$perim;mylist[[i]]@data$perim

  } 
}
```

from this I only get the perimeter of the first element.

[image]

How can I store all my values without loosing the previous one every time?(e.g perimeter 1355,1211,..)

Comment: you are overwriting datafr$perimeter[1] every loop. instead of [1] you need [i]

Comment: No. If I use [i] then I will not have my values in the same cell separated by ','. The values will be stored in three different lines. I want something like 154,526,442 (all values in a cell).

Comment: paste(sapply(mylist, function(x) x$perim), collapse = ",") assuming 1 row each

Comment: x@data$perim not x$perim

Comment: mdsummer the x is the dataframe?

Comment: without @, the people won't get a notification.